what is the syn type/struct that represents the nested field offset parameter to offset_of! macro?
If I want to wrap a macro around offset_of!'s nested form, e.g. offset_of!(Foo, x.y.VariantA.0), what should x.y.VariantA.0 get parsed as in syn terms (e.g. which of these https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/index.html#structs)?
The closest seems to be ExprField, but afaict that represents just a single field, not the sequence.
<filler text for 300 char requirement; I feel that my question is fully specified>

ExprField, its base can be any Expr, including Expr::Field(ExprField) and thus allows recursive parsing of "x.y.VariantA.0":
fn main() {
    let x: Result<syn::ExprField, _> = syn::parse2("x.y.VariantA.0".parse().unwrap());
    dbg!(x);
}

Relevant excerpt of the output:
[src/main.rs:3:5] x = Ok(
    ExprField {
        base: Expr::Field {
            base: Expr::Field {
                base: Expr::Path { x },
                member: Member::Named( y ),
            },
            member: Member::Named( VariantA ),
        },
        member: Member::Unnamed( 0 ),
    },
)

Playground

hmm. This isn't quite right. In offset_of, the initial x is already a field, and i believe this treats it as a struct for which y is the top-level field. In particular, this code breaks when parsing just the string "x", which is completely valid for offset_of

I ended up using Vec<syn::Member> as representation, and interpolating it into my macro output as offset_of!(#base_type, #(nested_fields).*)

@ajp syntactically it's parsed as plain expr i.e. syn::Expr.
